# ionic - list is slightly bigger than container

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic app.

I've just noticed that the list I'm using, is slightly bigger than it's container.

At first, I  though it was related to the border, but it is not.

I  know that it's not a deal breaker, but it does look odd to me, and i'd like this list to look nice and contained by the container without exit (even if it's only a couple of pixels)

You can see an example here: http://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/VaogjL

If you look closer, you can see that everything beneath **connection setting** list divider is outside.

The code i'm using is a simple list from ionic docs:

```
<div class="hg-login-card-advanced-connection-settings">
    <div class="list">
         <div class="item item-divider">Connection Settings</div>
            <div ng-repeat="conn in connections">
               <item class="item item-toggle">
                {{conn.name}}
                  <label class="toggle toggle-primary">
                     <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{conn.checked}}" ng-model="conn.checked">

                      <div class="track">
                      <div class="handle"></div>
                     </div>
                   </label>
                  </item>
                  <item class="item hg-login-card-advanced-connection-settings-details" ng-show="conn.checked==true">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="testing">
                    <small class="hg-login-card-advanced-connection-settings-details-status">Status</small>
                  </item>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

How can I fix this? Thanks for any feedback and suggestion

Comment: Is this bootstrap layout of some iconic special bootstrap based layout? Because it doesn't seem to play by bootstrap's rules to me.

Comment: It's not bootstrap, it uses default ionic stuff, no external libraries at all

Comment: Ah, I misjudged seeing `bootstrapcdn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.item` has a minus margin which leads to your problem. Replacing the css with this fixes the problem:

```
.item {
  margin: 0;
}
```

I don't know why this would be happening though. It's the ionic basic css. I guess it's their way of dealing or should I say hiding the left and right border of an item.

Comment: yes, found it. It has a margin of -1px for some reason. Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: yes, found it. It has a margin of -1px for some reason. Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: Yeah np. I edited the answer that it's just probably their way of dealing with the left and right borders of an item.